# Docker connect to localhost

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I have some simple code that doesn't work when running on a docker container.

```php
    $h = curl_init();
    $header = [
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0',
        'Referer: https://shoots.video',
    ];
    $url = str_replace("localhost:8080","localhost",$url);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);     
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($h, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $content = curl_exec($h);
    if ( curl_errno($h) ) {
        echo "Curl Error: " . curl_error($h);
    }
    curl_close($h);
    echo $content;
    var_dump($content);
    echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Above I am trying both curl and file_get_contents. I simply want to connect to the apache instance running on the docker container to load a webpage.

What I get is:

```
string(0) ""

Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost/flat-listings/?search_location=&search_radius=50&per_page=25&page=1&order=desc&orderby=rating-desc): failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address
```

The var_dump for the curl request is blank.

And file_get_contents throws a warning.

I have tried variations host.docker.internal, 127.0.0.1, $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] all with varying failures.

The containers are run from a docker-compose file, so if there's something I can put in the docker-compose.yml to fix it, that's cool.

Please understand, I want 100% localhost behavior. Nothing else. I want to connect to the container, from inside the container. I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work? I don't want to connect to mysql, or something else. It's just a php script that connects back to the HTTP server with a request for another page on the same "website".

I am using Docker on linux.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  mysql: 
    image: mariadb
    container_name: shootsmysql
    volumes:
      - vshootsdb:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress1
      MYSQL_USER: wordy
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
  wordpress:
    image: andreccosta/wordpress-xdebug
    container_name: shootswordpress
    volumes:
      - vshootswp:/var/www/html/
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress1
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordy
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xxxx
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp1_
    links:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    expose:
      - '80'
volumes:
  vshootsdb: 
  vshootswp: 
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /var/www/shoots/wordpress/
```

I have already looked at several possible solutions (including from SO), and either a) I couldn't get them to work or b) I didn't understand the answer well enough to implement it.

So I am looking for a bit more info than just: "Pass -network=host like the docs say". I have tried adding network_mode: "host" to the wordpress definition, to no joy.

Comment: To double-check, you're making a call from application code to the HTTP interface of the same service?  `localhost` should work there.  Your URL mentions port 8080 but your `docker-compose.yml` has port 80, are both port settings correct?

Comment: The code removes the 8080, the reason it is there is because this is a wordpress installation, so the url is set by that method. The ports are being forwarded (successfully) all other parts of the website work, just not this one script.

Comment: write docker ps, you can see the exposed ports

Answer (score 1):

You could use docker network mode host: https://docs.docker.com/network/host/
if you are in Linux, but all virtual domains will change

Comment: I have specifically tried that with no joy. To be clear, I used network_mode: "host" in the docker-compose. So that doesn't mean I did it correctly...